# Expressing "equals" in pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I was just wondering if there is a special way of saying when something equals something. For example in python, if you declare something equals 2, you say something = 2, whereas when you check if something equals something else, you would say:
if something == somethingelse:

So my question is in pseudocode for algorithms if I'm checking to see if a entered password equals a stored password in an IF THEN ELSE ENDIF loop, would I use one or two equal signs:

```
WHILE attempts < 3
    Get EnteredPassword
    **IF EnteredPassword = StoredPassword THEN**
        Validated = TRUE
    ELSE
        attempts = attempts + 1
    ENDIF
ENDWHILE
```

Comment: thanks, dont know why i didnt do that to begin with

Comment: I don't think there is a specific syntax for pseudocode. As long as it is clear that this is a comparison and not an assignment, you can use any form you want.

Comment: alright ill just keep one equal sign

Comment: Also, in mathematical-style pseudocode, assignment is indicated by the symbol `←` or `:=`. For example, `i ← 1` or `i := 1`. The `=` symbol is used for comparison.

Comment: interesting ill keep that in mind thanks bro :)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, pseudocode is very broad and every author has their own way of expressing it. As
Aziz has noted, usually x <- 1 is used for an assignment and x := x + 1 for an update. Read ':=' as 'becomes' instead of 'equals', however, they are interchangeably used. As for your question, both = and == are accepted answers, as long as it is clear to your reader what your intention is.

Answer (score 0):

To express equals you use the equal mark symbol once, unlike in python where you use the symbol twice to compare two values  (eg if variable == 'one'). An example syntax is:

variable = 'one'

WHILE variable = 'one' DO

SEND "hi" TO DISPLAY